# Looking for advice on moving an existing asp.net/sql server web site to Azure VMs

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud, virtual-machine, synchronization

I'm doing research into moving an existing asp.net web site with a sql server back end to Azure VM's.  We're limited to VM's due to the nature of the existing site and so pure azure is out of the question.  My current thinking is a a series of cloned web site vms in a round robin load balance configuration each pointing to a single sql server vm.  The sql server vm would be cloned as part of a fault tolerance configuration and the two would be kept in sync with SQL Sync.

We also need the capability to keep both the web site vms and sql server vms up to date with both OS and software patches and so each would be in it's own update and fault domains.

Can anyone confirm this is all viable or perhaps suggest alternate approaches?

Main concerns are:

- The a single instance of the sql server must be available to each instance of the web site.
- The sql server will contain financial data so must be both secure and backed up as often as feasible.
- We'd want the option to eventually expand the load capacity of the sql server, possibly via a server farm
- The web site needs to allow for an expected rapid growth in the number of users over the coming months/years
- The web site vms need to allow for weekly updates in the form of news articles, faq changes, etc.. and so these changes must be able to be synced across all vms

Answer (score 1):

This in general looks like it will work. Here are some ideas:

1. Two VMs with SQL serving syncing to SQL Azure with SQL Sync will
   work, but I think the shortest sync cycle you can have is 5 minutes.
   Make sure that is acceptable to your SLAs.
2. Check out the trust center for Azure to answer your questions about
   security and financial data. Often your own company will have to make
   that decision for yourselves.
   http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/
3. You could expand the SQL footprint by adding more SQL Servers to your VM pool, or by making the servers running the SQL VMs larger (up to extra large). SQL generally prefers fewer and bigger servers rather than many smaller servers.
4. Remember that different parts of your solution can use different parts of Azure. In this case you are using VMs for SQL (because your needs go beyond what SQL Azure can provide I think). You said your app needs the customization of VMs because of its architecture. That is fine. Upload a web server template, and then spawn your VMs from that. When you want to scale up, just spawn a new one from that template.
5. Going the IaaS/VM route will remove a lot of the benefits Azure/cloud can do for you, so I would start refactoring pieces of that app as quickly as you can to move to cloud services, or even web sites.
6. To sync the weekly content changes across web server VMs, I would do that however you are doing it today. Some people use robocopy to do this (or an equivalent). You could move that content to a shared blob container that each server points to, or to the shared database. The less actual content you have on a web server, usually the better. What I mean, is move static resource to blob containers (for sharing, redundancy, and eventual CDN perf boosts), and dynamic data to tables/queues/databases.

Please contact me if you want to have a deeper conversation.
Brian

Comment: Brian, thanks for the help.  I do have some other questions if you're up for it.  Been trying set up a simple model in Azure, just using the VM's, availability sets, end points, etc...  What I've noticed so far: 1) while I can join VM's via an availability set they don't end up in different update domains as I've read they should.  2) I've created a Traffic Manager Policy to setup failover for sql VMs, but I've found the system lists the policy as Degraded and poll state as offline.  3) any clue how to allow the round robin-ed VMs to see the sql server failover ones, would this be via a VN?

Comment: can you email me directly, and we can go through the scenario in more depth? Email should be in my profile.

Comment: Brian, I looked into the Azure Files because I was looking for the same type of solution, but discovered it cannot be accessed by VMs that are in a different Geo region than the Storage account. That pretty much kills any geo-redundant web hosting synchronization.